# Django, path to template encoding

Tags: python, django, encoding

I'm new to Python and Django and I'm having some trouble following the Django Tutorial

I've configured Django in the settings.py to fetch a custom template from a path. However, the name of the folder contains latin characters, so Python outputs the following Error: Non-ASCII character '\xe3' in file C:\Users\Joòo Dias....

I've tried to put `#coding iso8859-1` but another similar error appears, but now saying that UTF-8 couldn't convert the character.

The error occurs on the TEMPLATE_DIRS definition

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    'C:/Users/João Dias/PythonProjects/test27/templates'
)
```

Any idea on how can I solve this?? Thank you!

Comment: Why Latin folder name. Make your life easier if that was a the cause, change it.

Comment: Because my name is Portuguese and has special chars, and, my home folder has my name... Is thera any "non-easy" solution?

Comment: How did you use the template ? Not sure if we could encode the template_dirs in settings.py. That's one way to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm just following the django tutorial, and I'm this part
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial02/- The template is the default template from admin page in Django

Comment: Where does that error happen?

Comment: I've edited the post info to include the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I was using `#coding UTF-8` comment but, switching to `#encoding UTF-8` seems to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

When you write non-ASCII string literals in source files, you need to set the literal encoding in the `# coding` comment. If your file is in thr UTF8 encoding you need to write `# coding: utf-8`, not `#coding iso8859-1`.

Comment: I get another error `'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 11: invalid continuation byte. You passed in 'C:/Users/Jo\xe3o Dias/PythonProjects/test27/templates'`

Comment: Then the file is not in UTF-8.

Comment: Strange... I've just followed the tutorial. It wasn't me who created the file, it's a django auto generated file...? How can I bypass this without changing the folder's name, if possible???

Comment: @JoãoDias if django created the file with that line, just make sure your `coding` comment contains the encoding of the file, whatever it is.

Comment: How can I check which encoding the file was created?